# Вопрос про модель в MVC

Tags: php, yii2, mvc

Здравствуйте, я смотрел, как делают два разных человека сайт и так и не понял, откуда брать данные из БД в модели или контроллере? ну, т.е. в модели мы пишем табл из который будет выборка, это понятно.

Один человек делал так: в модели название табл и все. А выборку он делал уже в контроллере, например:

```
$feeds = Feedback::find()->orderBy('RAND()')->limit(4)->all();
```

А другой выборку делал в модели, а в контроллере уже обращался к методу того класса, пример:

```
$categories = Category::getCategoriesList();
```

Как правильно или как лучше и что лучше всего делать в модели?)))

Comment: [«Толстые, тупые, уродливые контроллеры»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D0.B8.D0.B1.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B5_.D1.87.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BE.D1.88.D0.B8.D0.B1.D0.BA.D0.B8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для примера возьмем ваш пример. Выводим `$feeds = Feedback::find()->orderBy('RAND()')->limit(4)->all();` в контроллере и все работает. Завтра нужно тоже самое, но в другом контроллере (или методе)? Что тогда? Вот если мы создадим метод в модели, то сможем использовать все это и в других контроллерах.

```
public function getFeeds()
{
    return self::find()->orderBy('RAND()')->limit(4)->all();
}
```

Тут даже дело уже не в самом MVC, а в подходе к гибкости системы. Старайтесь всегда думать о том, что вдруг данный код понадобиться где-то ещё.

Я использую помимо моделей (**Models**) ещё и модели представления (**ViewModels**). Это очень удобно. Например есть модель **Users**:

```
class Users extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    //Behaviors...
    //Roles...
    //Relations

}
```

В данной модели я храню все методы, касаемо самого Yii (правила,связи, поведения и т.д.). Не засоряю данный класс. Для остальных же методов использую **UsersViewModel**:

```
class UsersViewModel extends Users
{

    public static function getAllUsers()
    {
        return Users::find()->all();
    }

}
```

Я привел для примера примитивный пример, но важна сама суть. Старайтесь всегда думать на шаг вперед, чтобы потом не возвращаться на 2 шага назад.

[Лучшие практики MVC. На примере Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html)

Comment: Хороший ответ. Пока не приходится отклонится от примитивных запросов до административной части. Там приходится много сортировать, объединять, лимитировать...

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто. Согласно правилам MVC - контроллер является посредником между view и моделью и по сему модель вызывает контроллер и уже из подгруженной модели передает данные. Сие есть правильно. А в модели нужно описывать связи с другими моделями или поведение этой модели.

Comment: А не контроллер ли должен вызывать модель? А модель уже работать с базой и возвращать модель данных в контроллер, а он в свою очередь во view?